# Refreshing picture in drawingPanel extends JPanel

Tags: swing, drawing, refresh, jpanel

I have to load a small icon on the botton of my software. just to have a loading/ok/error icon. as sudgested on "http://www.particle.kth.se/~lindsey/JavaCourse/Book/Part1/Java/Chapter06/images.html" i create a dwowing panel extending JPanel.

```
class drawingPanel extends JPanel
{
    Image img;

    drawingPanel (Image img){
        this.img = img;
    }

    public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent (g);

        // Use the image width & height to find the starting point
        int imgX = getSize ().width/2 - img.getWidth (this);
        int imgY = getSize ().height/2 - img.getHeight (this);

        //Draw image centered in the middle of the panel    
        g.drawImage (img, imgX, imgY, this);
    } // paintComponent

}
```

I initialize the component in the following way:

```
// Grab the image.
Image img = new ImageIcon(iconPath+"ok.png").getImage();
// Create an instance of DrawingPanel
iconPanel = new drawingPanel(img);
```

all works well but at runtime i want to be able to change the icon within the pannel. i tryed all the fo;llowing but none managed to view the new picture:

```
Image img = new ImageIcon(iconPath+"loading.gif").getImage();
// Create a new  instance of DrawingPanel
this.iconPanel = new drawingPanel(img);
this.iconPanel.repaint();
this.iconPanel.revalidate();
this.iconPanel.repaint();
this.repaint();
this.revalidate();
```

(i tryed this because the class in whic i am writing the code is another extension of JPanel that contains IconPanel. Any idea about why i do not manage to change the picture?

Thanks,
Stefano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing don't start class name with small name. Rename `drawingPanel` to `DrawingPanel`.

I have tried making a simple demo based on your description and it works fine. The image in panel is changing perfectly.

```
public class Demo {

    public Demo() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        // Grab the image.
        Image img = new ImageIcon("1.png").getImage();
        // Create an instance of DrawingPanel
        final DrawingPanel iconPanel = new DrawingPanel(img);

        frame.add(iconPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JButton button = new JButton("Change image..");
        frame.add(button, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                iconPanel.setImg(new ImageIcon("2.png").getImage());
                iconPanel.repaint();
            }
        });

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Demo();
    }
}

class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {
    Image img;

    DrawingPanel(Image img) {
        this.img = img;
    }

    public void setImg(Image img) {
        this.img = img;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        // Use the image width & height to find the starting point
        int imgX = getSize().width / 2 - img.getWidth(this);
        int imgY = getSize().height / 2 - img.getHeight(this);

        // Draw image centered in the middle of the panel
        g.drawImage(img, imgX, imgY, this);
    } // paintComponent

}
```

The changes I have made is add a setter method of `img` in `DrawingPanel` class. So instead of creating new `DrawingPanel` you just have to call setImg() with new Image and then call reapint to paint the new image.